# f# out of bounds exception because list comprehension generates more than I expect

Tags: f#

I'm making a function that takes a Map and generates all the possible swaps of values.

```
let mutations setup =
  let setupList = setup |> Map.toList
  [for x in 0..(setupList.Length-1) do
    for y in x..(setupList.Length-1) do
      yield (x, y)]
  |> Seq.map (fun (x,y) ->
    setupList
    |> swapSndAt x y
    |> Map.ofList)
  |> Seq.distinct
```

Here is the code for `swapSndAt`:

```
let swapSndAt i1 i2 xs =
  let f1,s1 = xs |> List.item i1
  let f2,s2 = xs |> List.item i2
  xs |> List.mapi (fun i x ->
    if i = i1 then f1,s2
    else if i = i2 then f2,s1
    else x)
```

When I run this, I get an `System.ArgumentException: The index was outside the range of elements in the list.` at the point where I am calling `List.item` in `swapSndAt`.

How can that be, since the List comprehension makes sure to watch the bounds?

Comment: Are you sure this does what you want?  For example  `let l = [("a",1);("b",2);("c",3)] |> Map.ofList `;    `mutations l   |> Seq.toList`     gives me:    `val it : (int * int) list = [(0, 0); (0, 1); (0, 2); (1, 1); (1, 2); (2, 2)]`

Comment: Your code works perfectly well for me, [see fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tl3YHo). Perhaps this fails on some particular input? If so, would you care to share that input?

Comment: Unrelated to the question: you may want to consider bringing the code within `Seq.map` into the list comprehension. There is really no need to have it as a separate call, looks ugly.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `Map.toList` instead of `Map.toArray`? You're calling `List.item` (an O(N) operation) repeatedly (about O(N^2) times), which makes your overall algorithm O(N^3). You'd be better off with an array as, since indexing an array is constant time and your overall runtime would be down to O(N^2).

Comment: @FyodorSoikin turns out, the code was correct like you said.  An old version of the code didn't check bounds, and I didn't reload the functions into f# interactive properly; sorry for the unnecessary question. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @rmunn good smell catch